# iOS Simulator Keyboard Input Delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, delayed-execution, ios-simulator

Whenever I use the keyboard in the iOS Simulator, I get about a 5 second delay from when I tap a key and when the input appears. And I get a similar experience with the UIPicker. Everything else runs at normal speed.

This problem only started after I upgraded to the latest version of Snow Leopard. I am currently on 10.6.8. I was using the 4.0 Simulator at the time with XCode 3.2.6.

I have since upgraded to latest XCode 4.2 with the iOS 5.0 Simulator, but problem persists.

My problem is the same as the one reported here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/75735-sluggish-keyboard-input-ios-simulator.html

I am using a MacBook Pro with 2 GHz Intel Core i7 with 4 GB of DDR3.

It looks like an Apple engineer has screwed something up in one of the OS X upgrade. Maybe it has been fixed in Lion, but upgrading to Lion will be a last resort.

### Edit:

I have tried completely reinstalling XCode 3.2.6 and 4.2, and I have created several new projects which just have a text field.

Also I am not running any other programs, and my ram usage and cpu cycles are quite low.

It looks like the only solution will be to file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sometimes there are problems with project, Try cleaning up your project and restart your simulator.
2. Do you implement method which listen keyboard popups? If yes are you doing lots of calculation before keyboard pops up? Such as changing your GUI to re position your text boxes and images? If yes you have to re think your design :)
3. A weird one but when you experience delay, Open terminal window and type 'top' and than press return key. Check what process are running and check whether any process is using too much CPU.
4. For testing purpose try creating a very simple application like this this, Which has only one UITextView and when you click keyboard pups up. If you still experiencing a delay. than jump to step 5.

[image]

Step 5 - Log onto this website : http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and report this bug for future enhancement.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried everything else, except file a bug with Apple, so I'll do not now, but I won't hold my breath that they'll do anything about it.

Comment: Intereasting, So haven't found any abnormal behaviour inside your 'top' list? Hmm that means it is 100% compatibility issue. OSXLion is FTW!(Not marketing it but  still it's good :) )

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem after I loaded a beta version of Xcode, then went back to the production version. It seems some files are not kept in the application container and I had to wipe the OS (I know drastic) to fix it.